# Can't open localhost in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer

Firefox works.
Here is the error message in IE11.

```
There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.
The security certificate presented by this website is not secure.
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.  
We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.     
•If you arrived at this page by clicking a link, check the website address in the address bar to be sure that it is the address you were expecting.
•When going to a website with an address such as https://example.com, try adding the 'www' to the address, https://www.example.com.
For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.
```

I have added http://localhost , https://localhost , https://127.0.0.1, to the Trusted Sites list. 
I have turned off Require Server Verification For All Sites In This Zone, and Enable Protected Mode.

Comment: so why is IE rejecting the cert? Did you use a CA that isn't one of IE's trusted CAs?

Comment: I don't know, it's supposed to be a self-signed cert.